# Effective permittivity of multiphase system

Tags: electric-fields, maxwell-equations, microwaves

I am simulating the microwave heating of a packed bed of solid spheres. This consists of a discrete phase made of the solid spheres and a continuous phase in between. In order to simplify the problem and avoid meshing tens of thousands of spheres, I am simulating a just a part of the geometry containing some of the spheres hoping that I can calculate the apparent permittivity of this volume from the simulation results and then use it for a bigger and faster simulation.

I was using the following constitutive relation

$$ \epsilon = D / E $$

where $\epsilon$ is the material's permittivity, $D$ is the electric displacement field and $E$ is the electric field. $\epsilon$ is a complex number, where the real part is related to the electrical energy storage capacity of the material from the electric field, and the imaginary part is related to the dissipation of this energy.

I was wondering that using this simple relationship, I could get the apparent permittivity of the media. When using it only for the discrete phase (spheres), and carrying out a volumetric integration over the same component of $E$ and $D$ -say $E_{x}$ and $D_{x}$-,

$$ \epsilon_{app} = \frac{\int_V D_x  dV} {\int_V E_x  dV} $$

I get the exact same value I set for this phase which was of $10-1*j$.

However, when trying to integrate over a cube where both materials are present (the discrete phase of the particles and the continuum one), I get an $\epsilon$ value of $1.0087+0.0094725*j$, which is nonsensical as the convention in this software is that for lossy materials the imaginary part should be negative.

I would appreciate if someone could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to provide a quick update on this. While conducting the literature review, I noticed that the approach discussed was primarily used for symmetrical particle configurations. However, in my specific case, the position of the particles is defined in a DEM simulation, which results in a non-symmetrical setup.

Consequently, the permittivity of the material in this problem obtained in the way defined in my original post will not be represented by a simple complex number. Instead, it will be described by a tensor of complex numbers. I guess this means that the issue that the elements of the diagonal of the tensor have a positive imaginary component can result on negative 'apparent' imaginary component when considering the non-diagonal elements.

It looks like calculating the properties of an 'apparent' isotropic material that exhibits equivalent losses to the anisotropic one will require a mathematical development based on the formulation of electromagnetic losses. This would involve determining the closest isotropic material that can replicate the same level of losses.

I will continue exploring this avenue and provide further updates as I progress.